# Printing taxonomy terms in node.tpl

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I am trying to print taxonomy terms using this code:

```
<?php foreach ((array)$taxonomy as $item) { ?>
<a href="<?php print base_path() . "taxonomy/term/" . $item->tid; ?> "class='tags'><?php print $item->name ?>,</a>
<?php } ?>
```

It works fine if I put in contemplate, however it doesn't in the full node (node.tpl.php), the tags are empty in the full node. Can any one tell me what is the reason for this and how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the $taxonomy variable is populated in node.tpl.php of your theme?

Comment: No, how can I do this?

Comment: Place this:
<h1> value of tax var is: <?php print print_r($taxonomy, TRUE); ?> </h1>
In your node.tpl.php page. That is prob. the easiest way. Unless you have Devel module installed, if so just use <?php dsm($taxonomy); ?> in the template instead.

Answer (score 2):

First verify that the $taxonomy variable is available and populated in your node.tpl.php file. ...

EDIT:

Your accessing the values in your $item variable like it is an object but your casting to an array. Try accessing as an array:

```
 <a href="<?php print base_path() . "taxonomy/term/" . $item['tid']; ?> "class='tags'><?php print $item['name'] ?>,</a>
```

Comment: OK, the variable is available, however still it is not printed..

Comment: Nothing..It seems liek some declaration is missing as the code works correctly when (if teaser) but doesnt work wjen (if full node)...

Comment: @Vafello Wait. Can you post the results of the dsm print of the $taxonomy variable?  It may be that you have to specify which Vocabulary you want printed.